# PowerShell Command via SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh

I need to append a content of one file to another on remote machine running WinServer 2012 r2 from macOS. I have a bash script for this with these two lines

```
command="\"& {Get-Content -Path $readfile | Add-Content -Path $keyfile}\""
ssh -t user@server "powershell -Command $command"
```

and that doesn't work.

But if I write in my script this

```
echo "powershell -Command $command"
```

and then manually connect to server via SSH from my Terminal app and paste there the output from the previous command, it works well. What am I missing?

My SSH connection is maintained with keys, so I don't need to enter passwords on connecting.

Comment: wouldn't `command="& {Get-Content -Path \$readfile | Add-Content -Path \$keyfile}"` or `command='& {Get-Content -Path $readfile | Add-Content -Path $keyfile}'` work better?

Comment: No, that's not working either. The first suggestion returns an error. The second silently does nothing.